# Binding a listbox SelectedItem ngPrime to an Observable Collection Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, primeng

I have problem using ngPrime listbox in Angular2. I am downloading array of objects from firebase as observable and trying to display it properly in listbox;

```
<div *ngIf="addContactDialogVisible==true">
<h3>Pick Contact</h3>
<p-listbox [options]="contactService.contacts|async"
           [style]="{'width':'250px','max-height':'250px'}">
  <template let-c>
    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
      <avatar-component [key]="c.$key" [avatarSize]="50"
                        style="display:inline-block;margin:5px 0 0 5px"></avatar-component>
      <div style="font-size:15px;float:right;margin:15px 10px 0 0">{{c.name}} {{c.surname}}</div>
    </div>
  </template>
  <button pButton type="text" (click)="send()" icon="fa-check" label="Upload"></button>
</p-listbox>
```

The problem is that contactService.contacts should be in ngPrime SelectItem[] and that is why all the items all selected. 
What is more the SelectItem object look like this:{label:'New York', value:'New York'}, my does not have label.
How to do this work correctly?

component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {CalendarService} from '../common/services/calendar.service';
import {SimplyCalendarModel} from './calendar.model';
import {ContactService} from '../common/services/contact.service';
import {ContactWithKey} from '../contacts/models/contact.model';
import {SelectItem} from '../../../assets/primeng/components/common/api';
@Component({
  selector: 'calendar-component',
  template: require('./calendar.component.html'),
})

export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {

 // con: SelectItem[];

  header: any;
  addContactDialogVisible: boolean = false;
  pickContact: ContactWithKey;

  constructor(
              private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
              private contactService: ContactService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactService.getContacts();

    this.header = {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    };
  }

  handleDayClick(e) {
    this.addContactDialogVisible=true;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

service:

```
public contacts: FirebaseListObservable<ContactWithKey[]>;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
  }

  getContacts() {
    this.contacts = this.af.database.list('data/contacts');
    this.af.database.list('data/contacts')
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

Comment: Can you please post your component class code.

Comment: i have edited my post, but as you can see, it is not much.

Comment: Is `contactService.contacts` an Observable?  Can you please post your `ContactService` code.

Comment: okay, now i thin i have to change my ContactWithKey model to model like this {label:'',value:''}, but i do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get started. You'll need to declare your `contacts` variable in the component, which you will populate from your service. And then your template HTML can then subscribe to `contacts` and fetch the data for you. Here are the steps.

Change this line in **calendar.component.html** from:

```
<p-listbox [options]="contactService.contacts|async"
  [style]="{'width':'250px','max-height':'250px'}">
```

to:

```
<p-listbox [options]="contacts | async"
  [style]="{'width':'250px','max-height':'250px'}">
```

Update **calendar.component.ts** from:

```
header: any;
```

to:

```
header: any;
contacts: FirebaseListObservable<ContactWithKey[]>;
```

**NOTE:** You will have to import `FirebaseListObservable` to the top of `calendar.component.ts`

Finally update **calendar.service.ts**

```
getContacts() {
  return this.af.database.list('data/contacts');
}
```